# How to get categories by store or website

Tags: magento-1.9, category

I need to display the categories based on the website.
Somebody help me
How to get categories based on store or website?

Answer (score 6):

you will get by this root category. the stores are related with the root category.in `admin panel` you can see in `manage store`.

```
$storeid=Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    $rootid     = Mage::app()->getStore($storeid)->getRootCategoryId();
            $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addFieldToFilter('path', array('like'=> "1/$rootid/%"));
```

Comment: From your code where i can give website id?  @Qaisar Satti

Answer (score 2):

Get store specific categories

The following code will fetch all active store specific categories. The following helper function does so:-

```
getStoreCategories($sorted=false, $asCollection=false, $toLoad=true)

$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');

// sorted by name, fetched as collection
$categoriesCollection = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', true, false);

// sorted by name, fetched as array
$categoriesArray = $helper->getStoreCategories('name', false, false);
```

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the categories for specific store id:

```
$allCategories = Mage::getModel ( 'catalog/category' )->setStoreId(7);
$categoryTree = $allCategories->getTreeModel();
$categoryIds = $categoryTree->getCollection()->getAllIds();
```

if further want to get its data save in csv file:

```
if ($categoryIds) {
            $outputFile = "var/export/categories-and-ids.csv";
            $write = fopen($outputFile, 'w');
            foreach ( $categoryIds as $categoryId ) {
                $parentId = $allCategories->load($categoryId)->getParentId();
                $data = array($parentId, $allCategories->load($categoryId)->getName(), $categoryId);
                fputcsv($write, $data);
            }
        }
        fclose($write);
```